# Convert to decimal direct

Tags: c#

I´m trying to convert this string value "153565" to this decimal "1535.65".

I dont want to add a dot and then convert to decimal. It is possible to make a direct conversion with decimal?

Comment: why not divide by 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse to decimal and divide through 100:

```
decimal dec = decimal.Parse("153565") / 100;
```